# VirtualBox not accepting keyboard input

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install a system on my VM. I boot the VM using a bootable CD and then I have to change the bootable CD to install my system. As soon as I change my CD after booting, the VM stops accepting keyboard inputs...

What's wrong? If I did not change the CD/DVD then it accepts keywords.

Comment: Did you click the mouse in the VM window to [capture the keyboard](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html)?

Comment: If I click with mouse, mouse dissapears.. it re-appears if I click ctrl+alt+del

Comment: It is quite possible that your vm is taking its time to read the cd or install components from it. If this is during install time of the OS, then it is also normal to not have a mouse capture. What OS is your VM running?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.8...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Mac OSX 10.6.8 and Virtual Box 4.2.14. When Debian 7 had booted to the install screen, the keyboard wasn't responding at all.

The solution in my case was to change the installed version to be Debian (64-bit) instead of Debian. After that the keyboard worked just fine.

[image]